# Apex Office Print Plugin : Error when downloading pdf report

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I imported AOP plugin to my application for making a report with a customized template made in word and then linked to a button using a process but when the button is clicked, following error appears:-

```
     ORA-06550: line 4, column 46: PLS-00201: identifier 
    'AOP_API3_PKG.F_PROCESS_AOP' must be declared ORA-06550: line 4, column 
     1: PL/SQL: Statement ignored.
```

From AOP documentation, i learned that for Apex 5.1,I must import dynamic_action_plugin_be_apexrnd_aop_da_51 instead of process_type_plugin. Doing so leads to another error in the Sql query i.e `wrong number of columns selected in the Sql`. However i was able to run the page but with error as follows:-

```
    'AOP_API3_PKG.F_RENDER_AOP' must be declared.
```

[image: error]

Has LibreOffice necessarily be imported to the application to be able to print in PDF form?
Please can anyone help. Waiting for a prompt reply
Thanks

Comment: @Dmitry Please could you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you didn't run the script aop_db_pkg.sql which you find in the db folder in the parsing scheme your application is linked to.
See also: https://www.apexofficeprint.com/docs/#19-quick-install-guide

Can you verify if in SQL Workshop > Object Browser you see the package  aop_api3_pkg?

Comment: Thanks it helped. I oversaw that particular instruction in the guide. But now it says `ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`  even though the same query returns desired result without errors when executed in `SQL Workshop -> SQL Commands    select  
Sum(Purchase_price) as "opening_value", sum(CURR_PRED_DEP) as "depreciation" , sum(Net_value) as "closing_value" 

from LCD_Monitor;`

Comment: can you remove the ; at the end?

Comment: yes i did that but no effect. In the designer view, the error is displayed as wrong number of columns selected in the SQL query. After clicking the print button, it shows as SQL command not properly ended.Could the reason be that the column tags in the template is not equal to columns in the query?

Comment: which SQL query are you using? If you click on the Help in the Builder it should give you an example which format AOP expects.

You probably need something like:
inline `
select
    'file1' as "filename",
    cursor
    (select Sum(Purchase_price) as "opening_value", sum(CURR_PRED_DEP) as "depreciation" , sum(Net_value) as "closing_value" from LCD_Monitor
    ) as "data"
from dual 
`

If you have tags in the template that are not in the query it should not matter, they are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this plug-in you can use custom Dynamic Action to print a page.Create a Button with a Dynamic Action "Print", with true action : Execute Javascript Code

```
//// Collapse Left Navigation Bar If It Was Expanded ////
var navCollapsed = 0;
if ($("body").hasClass("js-navExpanded")) {
    $("#t_Button_navControl").click();
    navCollapsed = 1;
};
setTimeout(3000);



//////// Hide ////////

//Hide Navigation Bar List
$("#t_Header").hide();

//Hide Navigation Menu
$("#t_Body_nav").hide();

//Hide Breadcrumb
$("#t_Body_title").hide();

//Hide Content Offset
$("#t_Body_content_offset").hide();

//Hide Buttons
$(".t-Button").hide();

//Hide Footer
$(".t-Footer").hide();



////Print Preview Call////
window.print();



//////// Show ////////

//Show Navigation Bar List
$("#t_Header").show();

//Show Navigation Menu
$("#t_Body_nav").show();

//Show Breadcrumb
$("#t_Body_title").show();

//Show Content Offset
$("#t_Body_content_offset").show();

//Show Buttons
$(".t-Button").show();





//// Expand Left Navigation Bar If It Was Colapsed ////
if ( navCollapsed = 1 ) {
    $("#t_Button_navControl").click();
}
```